# How to force public schema for default schema Apartment Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I am using the Apartment gem with Unicorn and Nginx.  I am using the Subdomain elevator. In `initializers/apartment/subdomain_exclusions` I have `Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']`

My understanding is that the public schema should now be used either with the public subdomain, www subdomain, or no subdomain ie mydomain.com.

However, it doesn't work this way.  When I use www or no subdomain, it uses the last accessed schema.  So if I was just using another subdomain, it will use that schema.  This is not good.  I have even tried adding `config.default_schema = "public"` but this does nothing.

Any ideas why this is not working?  Does anyone have it setup in a similar way and only public schema is used when no subdomain is specified?  Is it possibly Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little late on this answer, but I ran into a similar situation and thought I would post the solution.

We needed to switch tenants based on the request path.  Our routes appended the tenant name to the front of the path (i.e. `/:tenant/some/action`).  The problem with this is all of the applications assets obviously fell under the assets path (i.e. `/assets/application.css`).  In addition we put in a admin console under the `/admin` path.

To solve this, I used the `Generic` middleware and passed a `proc`:

```
config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Generic',
                          Proc.new { |request|
                            path = request.path.split('/')[1]
                            Apartment.tenant_names.include?(path) ? path: 'public'
                      }
```

How I handled routing:

```
scope path: ':tenant', defaults: {tenant: 'default_tenant_if_necessary'} do
    resources :model
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do the job, didn't even consider that since thought that should be default behavior. I will try modifying that for subdomains and see how it works.

Comment: @tagCincy how did you change your routes to handle the tenant_name that is appended on every request? Do you do think on routes.rb or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because how it's implemented in `Generic` elevator. It doesn't switch schema to default if no matching database is found:

https://github.com/influitive/apartment/blob/development/lib/apartment/elevators/generic.rb#L21

I'm not sure it it's a bug or done on purpose.
I would suggest to subclass `Subdomain` elevator and overwrite call method.